# How to conditionally add key/value pairs to a dictionary within a function call?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm attempting to retrieve data from a Jira database and save to a Pandas data frame. Here's my code:

```
from jira import JIRA
import pandas as pd

cert_path = 'C:\\cert.crt'

start_date = '2020-10-01'
end_date = '2020-10-31'

# three different instances (each with their own schema)
a_session = JIRA(server='https://jira.myinstance-A.com', options={'verify': cert_path}, kerberos=True)

b_session = JIRA(server='https://jira.myinstance-B.com', options={'verify': cert_path}, kerberos=True)

c_session = JIRA(server='https://jira.myinstance-C.com', options={'verify': cert_path}, kerberos=True)


# define Jira queries
query_1 = 'project = \"Test Project 1\" and issuetype = Incident and resolution = Resolved and updated >= {} and updated <= {}'.format(start_date, end_date)

query_2 = 'project = \"Test Project 2\" and issuetype = Incident and resolution = Resolved and updated >= {} and updated <= {}'.format(start_date, end_date)

query_3 = 'project = \"Test Project 3\" and issuetype = Defect and resolution = Resolved and releasedate >= {} and releasedate <= {}'.format(start_date, end_date)

query_4 = 'project = \"Test Project 4\" and issuetype = Enhancement and resolution = Done and completed >= {} and completed <= {}'.format(start_date, end_date)


# fetch all issues from a given session for a given query
block_size = 100
block_num = 0


def get_all_issues(session, query):

    block_size = 50
    block_num = 0
    
    start = 0
    all_issues = []
    while True:
        issues = session.search_issues(query, start, block_size)
        if len(issues) == 0:
            # No more issues
            break
        start += len(issues)
        for issue in issues:
            all_issues.append(issue)

    issues = pd.DataFrame(issues)

    for issue in all_issues:
        d = {
            'jira_key' : issue.key,
            'issue_type' : issue.fields.type,
            'creator' : issue.fields.creator,
            'resolution' : issue.fields.resolution
             }

        issues = issues.append(d, ignore_index=True)

    return issues


# list of queries, and the corresponding backend
queries = [
    (a_session, query_1),
    (a_session, query_2),
    (b_session, query_3),
    (c_session, query_4),
]


# loop over each pair of session and query, calling the get_all_issues function, and save the dataframe we get each time
dataframes = []

for session, query in queries:
    dataframe = get_all_issues(session, query)
    dataframes.append(dataframe)


# concatenate all data frames
all = pd.concat(dataframes)
```

This code works just fine (because the `jira_key`, `issue_type`, `creator`, and `resolution` field names in the `d` dict are common to `a_session`, `b_session`, and `c_session`).

The problem arises when I try to introduce a custom field that might be present in, say, `a_session` but not in `b_session` or `c_session`.

For example:

```
for issue in all_issues:
    d = {
        'key' : issue.jira_key,
        'type' : issue.fields.issue_type,
        'creator' : issue.fields.creator,
        'resolution' : issue.fields.resolution,
        'system_change' : issue.fields.custom_field_123,  # only applicable to a_session and b_session
        'system_resources' : issue.fields.custom_field_456,  # only applicable to c_session
        'system_backup' : issue.fields.custom_field_789   # only applicable to b_session and c_session
         }
```

`custom_field_123` exists in `a_session` and `b_session`, but not in `c_session`.

`custom_field_456` exists only in `c_session`.

And, `custom_field_789` exists in `b_session` and `c_session`.

Running the code with this expanded dictionary results in the following error: `AttributeError: type object 'PropertyHolder' has no attribute 'custom_field_123'.`

I tried to add an `IF` statement before `for issue in all_issues:`, but that approach didn't work.

Is there a way to add key/value pairs to the `d` dictionary based on whether the field is relevant to a given `session`? For example, as `a_session/query_2` is running, only consider `custom_field_123` (because that's the only one that's valid) and **disregard** `custom_field_456` and `custom_field_789` (because passing these would result in the error message above).

Comment: I want the `system_change` key/value pair to simply not exist in the case where it doesn't exist/apply.  For example, `system_change` does not exist in `c_session` and should therefore not be passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'd need to add them separately. Something like:

```
d = {
    'key' : issue.jira_key,
    'type' : issue.fields.issue_type,
    'creator' : issue.fields.creator,
    'resolution' : issue.fields.resolution
}
fields = issue.fields  # For brevity
if hasattr(fields, "custom_field_123"):
    d['system_change'] = fields.custom_field_123
if hasattr(fields, "custom_field_456"):
    d['system_resources'] = fields.custom_field_456
if hasattr(fields, "custom_field_789"):
    d['system_backup'] = fields.custom_field_789
```

If you're on Python 3.8+ though, and the field values are never empty/None, you can make use of [`:=`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) and a defaulting [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) to reduce the duplication:

```
if value := getattr(fields, "custom_field_123", None):
    d['system_change'] = value
if value := getattr(fields, "custom_field_456", None):
    d['system_resources'] = value
if value := getattr(fields, "custom_field_789", None):
    d['system_backup'] = value
```